# Asp.net dynamically rendered label - AssociatedControlID throws an exception in handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler

Situation: a jQuery Ajax script calls ASP.NET generic handler, which in turn dynamically renders html code of an web asp.net control. There is a problem with AssociatedControlID property of a label which causes an exception. My code is:

```
public override PlaceHolder GetWebControl()
{
    // GetWrappingPlaceHolder() creates an placeholder
    PlaceHolder plh = this.GetWrappingPlaceHolder();

    var inputTextBox = new TextBox();
    inputTextBox.ID = "TextBox";
    inputTextBox.Text = this.Value;


    var label = this.GetLabel();
    label.AssociatedControlID = inputTextBox.ID;

    plh.Controls.Add(label);
    plh.Controls.Add(inputTextBox);

    return plh;
}
```

the above method is called from the handler:

```
var control = option.GetWebControl();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

control.RenderControl(htw);
```

the last line throws an exception.

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to find control with id 'TextBox' that
>   is associated with the Label 'Label'.

How can I solve this? Especially, without adding my control to dynamically created Web.UI.Page?

Comment: Please provide error details

Comment: Here is the exception: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to find control with id 'TextBox' that is associated with the Label 'Label'.

Comment: Please change the sequence of    plh.Controls.Add(inputTextBox);plh.Controls.Add(label); and try it